# The number of cosets of a Group $G$ and an invariant subgroup $H$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $A$ denotes the number of elements of a Group $G$ and $B$ the number of elements in an invariant subgroup $H$, I understand that each coset ${g_a H}$ contains $B$ elements of $G$. But why can we see immediately that there are $A/B$ cosets, but not $A-B$ cosets?

Answer (score 0):

Because cosets for a given subgroup form a *partition* of the whole group, in that each group element is in one of the cosets and any two cosets are either disjoint to each other or coincide.

> If $u\in gH$ then $u=gh$ for an $h\in H$, so $uH=ghH=gH$ because $h^{-1}\in H$, thus $hH=H$.