# A question regarding the proof of G a finite group, H a subgroup then $\left|G\right| = \left|G/H\right|\cdot \left|H\right| $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

I'm currently looking at the proof of the following statement:

let $\left(G,\cdot \right)$ be a finite group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, then:$$\left|G\right| =  \left|G/H\right|\cdot \left|H\right| $$

Now apparently it is sufficient to show that the number of elements in the left coset $a\cdot H$ is equal to the number of elements in the subgroup $H$ and that is done by proving that $\varphi:H \to a\cdot H$;  $\varphi\left(h\right)=a\cdot h $ is a bijection. I understand why is that a bijection and why is the number of elements in the left coset equal to the number of elements in the subgroup, but how does that prove the statement? What am I missing here?

Comment: Here are two previous questions about the same proof : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801674/suppose-g-is-a-finite-group-with-normal-subgroup-h-show-og-h-divides-o, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547124/the-number-of-cosets-of-a-group-g-and-an-invariant-subgroup-h Perhaps the answers could help you.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'm not sure that's my case. In the first question you've linked H is assumed to be a normal subgroup. Or is that the same as mine? And i don't see the connection with the second one unfortunately

Comment: The hypothesis that $H$ is normal is only needed to have a group structure on the quotient, but you don't need it to count the elements.

Comment: @strangeattractor: What does $G/H$ mean when $H$ is a *non-normal* subgroup of $G$? It seems as though normality was supposed to be mentioned, but was forgotten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $G$ is the disjoint union of the conjugate clases (the sets $a.H$) and there are $G/H$ such classes.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What do you mean by G/H such classes?

Comment: Since $G/H$ is, by definition, the set $\{a.H\,|\,a\in G\}$, $\#G/H$ is the number of conjugate classes.

Comment: of course that i understand, but unfortunately i still fail to see the connection of that with the mapping $\varphi$

Comment: @strangeattractor the point of this mapping is that, as you noted, its existence proves that the coset $aH$ has as many elements as $H$. But this is true for every coset! So the sum of the elements in all coset is simply their common number of elements multiplied by the number of cosets, and this gives you the formula.

Comment: @strangeattractor I have nothing to add to the previous comment.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you. I think I almost understand it now. But one more question if you don't mind. What do you mean by "their common number of elements"?

Comment: @strangeattractor The number of elements of the conjugate classes. It's the same number for all of them.

Comment: @strangeattractor I'm glad I could help.

Comment: In English, we call $aH$ a coset. I feel the phrase "conjugate classes" sounds too close to "conjugacy classes," which is a different concept.

Comment: @anon Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since all cosets have the same cardinality you can sort the elements of $G$ into a rectangular lattice, where the length of one side is $|H|$ (the size of any coset) and the length of the other side is $|G/H|$ (the amount of cosets).

Answer (score 1):

That

$\vert aH \vert = \vert H \vert, \tag 1$

i.e. that the cardinality of any coset is the same as the cardinality of the subgroup, is only half the story.  The other half is:

***(C) Cosets $aH$ of $H$ are either disjoint or identical.***

We may prove this as follows:  if

$aH \cap bH \ne \emptyset, \tag 2$

then there are

$h_1, h_2 \in H \tag 3$

with

$ah_1 = bh_2; \tag 4$

then

$a = bh_2h_1^{-1} \in bH, \tag 5$

and similarly

$b \in aH; \tag 6$

(5) and (6) are sufficient to force

$aH = bH, \tag 7$

since they show

$bH \subseteq aH, \; aH \subseteq bH; \tag 8$

thus we see that (C) must bind, which means that the distinct cosets of $H$ form a partition of $G$ into disjoint subsets of equal cardinality (and we note here that *every* $g \in G$ is in *some* coset, *viz.* $g \in gH$); the number of such cosets is

$[G:H] = \vert G \vert / \vert H \vert. \tag 9$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following relation on the set $G$:
$$
a\sim_H b \qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad a^{-1}b\in H
$$
This is an equivalence relation:

1. (reflexivity) $a\sim_H a$, because $a^{-1}a=1\in H$;
2. (symmetry) if $a\sim_H b$, then $a^{-1}b\in H$; therefore $(a^{-1}b)^{-1}=b^{-1}a\in H$, and so $b\sim_H a$;
3. (transitivity) if $a\sim_H b$ and $b\sim_H c$, then $a^{-1}b\in H$ and $b^{-1}c\in H$; therefore $(a^{-1}b)(b^{-1}c)=a^{-1}c\in H$ and so $a\sim_H c$.

Every equivalence relation on a set defines a partition of the same set via the equivalence classes: if $[a]_{\sim_H}=\{x\in G: a\sim_H x\}$, then two sets $[a]_{\sim_H}$ and $[b]_{\sim_H}$ are either equal or disjoint. It also holds, by reflexivity, that $a\in[a]_{\sim_H}$.

Now we can prove that $[a]_{\sim_H}=aH$. Indeed, if $a\sim_H x$, then $a^{-1}x\in H$, so $x=a(a^{-1}x)\in aH$; conversely, if $h\in H$, then $a\sim_H(ah)$, because $a^{-1}(ah)=h\in H$.

Since the equivalence classes are a partition of $G$, in order to count the elements of $G$ we just need to count the number of elements in each equivalence class and sum them up. However, you have proved that two equivalence classes (that is, the left cosets) have the same number of elements. Therefore $|G|$ is the number of elements in *one* coset times the number of cosets:
$$
|G|=|H|\cdot|G/H|
$$
because $H=1H$ is indeed one of the cosets.

---

If you consider the relation $\sim_H'$ defined by
$$
a\sim_H' b \qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad ab^{-1}\in H
$$
then the verifications are essentially the same as before, with the difference that $[a]_{\sim_H'}=Ha$, the *right* coset. Also the right cosets have the same cardinality as $H$, so we have proved that there are as many left cosets as right cosets.

This can also be proved by noticing that the map
$$
aH\mapsto Ha^{-1}
$$
is a bijection of the set of left cosets onto the set of right cosets (this doesn't require finiteness of the group $G$, so it's interesting on its own).